# Validating radiobuttons

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 60 different questions which you have to answer on a scale from 1 to 10 (with radio buttons).

Each answer is given with the code below:

```
<?php 

    echo $this->Form->create();
    $options = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4', '5' => '5', '6' => '6', '7' => '7', '8' => '8', '9' => '9', '10' => '10' );
    $attributes = array('legend' => false);

?>

<div class="answers">
    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->radio('answer1', $options, $attributes);
    ?>
</div>
```

The same thing for answer2, answer3,...

Now I want to validate to see if a radiobutton is actually clicked so not empty.
I have this:

```
public $validate = array( 
    'answer1' =>array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please choose an answer'
        )       
);
```

Is there a way to validate all 60 forms at once? Or do I have to input each answer in the `$validate`?

Comment: all 60 _forms_? you can use beforeValidate to generate the same validation rule for each answer

Comment: No only 1 form, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Put the names of the fields in an array and loop through it (in the constructor of the model)

```
$fields = array('answer1', 'answer2', 'answer3'); //all fields you need to validate
foreach($fields as $field) {
    $validate[$field] = array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please choose an answer'
    );
}
```

By the way, to check if the value of the button is valid (in your case a number between 1 and 10) you could use `inList`

```
public $validate = array(
    'function' => array(
        'allowedChoice' => array(
            'rule'    => array('inList', array('1', '2', '3', '4')) //And so on
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: How do I exclude one field in my table? (answer_id)

Comment: Just do not put it in the array `$fields`!

Comment: $fields = $this->Survey->find('all');
I've used this for to make my array.

Comment: To get the fields, better use `array_keys($this->YourModel->getColumnTypes());`, as `find` will not work if there are no surveys to find. Then, in the foreach loop, just check if `$field != 'answer_id'`.